# RegEx for matching HTML tags

Tags: regex, tags, extract, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to use regular expression to extract start tags in lines of a given HTML code. In the following lines I expect to get only 'body' and 'h1'as start tags in the first line and 'html','head' and 'title' as start tags in the second line:

I have already tried to do this using the following regular expression:

```
start_tags = re.findall(r'<(\w+)\s*.*?[^\/]>',line)
```

---

```
'<body data-modal-target class=\'3\'><h1>Website</h1><br /></body></html>'
'<html><head><title>HTML Parser - II</title></head>'
```

But my output for the first line is: ['body','h1','br'], while I do not expect to catch 'br' as I excluded '/'.

And for the second line is ['html','title'], whereas I expect to catch 'head' too. It would be a grate kind if you let me know which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674).

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to do so with regular expressions, you might want to design multiple different expressions, step by step. You may be able to connect them using OR pipes, but it may not be necessary.

#### RegEx 1 for h1-h6 tags

This link helps you to capture body tags excluding body and head:

```
(<(.*)>(.*)</([^br][A-Za-z0-9]+)>)
```

You might want to add more boundaries to it. For example, you can replace `(.*)` with lists of chars `[]`.

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualize your expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx 2 for head and body

For head and body tags, you might want to swipe the new lines, which you might want [an expression similar to](https://regex101.com/r/T6oWHD/1):

```
(<head>([\s\S]*)<\/head>)|(<body>([\s\S]*)</body>)
```

[image]

#### Performance

These expressions are rather expensive, you might want to simplify them, or write some other scripts to parse your HTMLs, or find a HTML parser maybe, to do so.

Comment: Thank you Emma for your explanations. I tried these lines that give me the start tags, end tags and empty tags respectively.

Comment: starttag = re.findall(r'<(\w+) *[^/]*?>',str2),      endtag = re.findall(r'</(\w+)>',str2),   emptytag = re.findall(r'<(\w+) />',str2) that gives me starttags=['body','h1'], endtags=['h1','body','html'], emptytag=['br'] for str2 =  '<body data-modal-target class=\'3\'><h1>Website</h1><br /></body></html>',  but still I don't know how should I merge them to get the following result:  Start : body  Start : h1   End : h1 Empty : br  End : body   End : html

Comment: I should mention it that I know for parsing data from HTML we have very useful libraries like Beautiful soup, here I am trying to do it using regex to learn more about regex. Thanks again.